# Append to protected file

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix

I want to do something along the lines of:

```
echo "Append string" >> protected_file
```

However, as this file is write protected I get an error. Running:

```
sudo echo "Append string" >> protected_file
```

seems to run sudo on the echo command, and still gives me the permission error, how do I append to this file?

Comment: You should `sudo` your shell script, not the `echo` command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
echo "Append string" | sudo tee -a protected_file >/dev/null
```

Comment: +1 for this -- unlike the accepted answer, it doesn't give extra privileges to anything that doesn't need them, which would be important if the content were generated by something more complicated than echo.

Comment: Why is the >/dev/null necessary?

Comment: @Richard: Because `tee` sends output to the file *and* to standard out (two places - like a "tee" in a pipe) and we don't want the extra output. Redirecting standard out to `/dev/null` discards it.

Answer (score 3):

For a literal answer,

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "Append string" >> protected_file'
```

But I agree with ShivanRaptor in principle.

Explanation: `>>` is a shell operator. If you invoke `sudo command`, you do not run another shell; thus you cannot redirect `echo` without also redirecting `sudo` (which, ultimately, gives you the wrong user id when doing the redirection). The trick is to launch a separate shell inside `sudo`, where you can issue the redirection operator.

Comment: Thanks, but this is just a single command I wrote on the cmd line, not inside a shell script

Answer (score 0):

or try this:

```
echo "echo 'append string' >> protected_file" | sudo bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting it all together and fixing one of the answers, there are 3 ways:

```
sudo su root -c "echo 'append string' > protected_file"
echo "echo 'append string' >> protected_file" | sudo bash
echo "append string" | sudo tee -a protected_file >/dev/null
```